# How to show all Callout labels?

Tags: labeling

```
expr = Uncompress[FromCharacterCode[
    Flatten[ImageData[Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pva9y.png"], "Byte"]]]];
ListLinePlot[expr, PlotRange -> All,ImageSize -> 1000]
```

[image]

As we see, it just 4 Callout labels? But how to show all Callout labels?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Documentation for Callout says, that "Callouts are pruned to avoid collisions" and advices to use "LabelVisibility" option to control this behaviour:

```
expr = Uncompress[FromCharacterCode[
Flatten[ImageData[Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pva9y.png"],"Byte"]]]] // 
    ReplaceAll[Callout[args___] :> Callout[args, LabelVisibility -> All]];
ListLinePlot[expr, PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> 1000]
```

[image: With LabelVisibility->All]

http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LabelVisibility.html

Comment: I cannot fully reproduce it in a simple example but I find that often the point that the `Callout` is attached to needs to be within the `PlotRange` in order for it to appear even when using `LabelVisibility->All`. This becomes relevant when combining plots and can be confusing since the points in a `ListPlot` outside the PlotRange do still get included. Just leaving this comment since it might help someone out who like me is confused why some Callouts still aren't visible.

Answer (score 7):

```
xy = MapIndexed[{#2[[1]], #} &, expr];

data1 = Cases[{p_, Callout[a_, b__]} :> Callout[{p, a}, b]] @ xy;

data2 = xy /. Callout -> (# &);

Show[ListLinePlot[data2], ListPlot[data1], ImageSize -> 800]
```

[image]